# Single user mode session lost after background processes jump in

Tags: sql-server-2008

We have an application using SQL server. This application restores DB very frequently using Single user mode. Following are the SQLs that are executed to restore the database in single user mode and to get the database back in multi user mode.

```
alter database [test-db] set single_user with rollback immediate;   
use master;restore database [test-db] from database_snapshot = 'snapshot_test-db';
alter database [test-db] set multi_user;
```

After switching the test-db to single user mode some 4-5 background processes of Taskmanager jump in and the application is no longer able to perform further actions (to restore database and alter database) on the database using the same session. These background process are deadlocked between them selves. Please refer to the output of sp_who2 below, specifically the lines starting with 16, 20, 21, 23, and 53.

```
13   ,BACKGROUND                    ,sa,  .,  .,master,BRKR EVENT HNDLR,0,27,11/28 16:13:40,                                              ,13   ,0    
14   ,BACKGROUND                    ,sa,  .,  .,master,BRKR TASK       ,0,0,11/28 16:13:40,                                              ,14   ,0    
15   ,sleeping                      ,sa,  .,  .,master,TASK MANAGER    ,0,2,11/28 16:13:40,                                              ,15   ,0    
16   ,BACKGROUND                    ,sa,  .,23   ,test-db,TASK MANAGER    ,16,5,11/28 16:13:40,                                              ,16   ,0    
17   ,BACKGROUND                    ,sa,  .,  .,master,BRKR TASK       ,0,0,11/28 16:13:40,                                              ,17   ,0    
18   ,BACKGROUND                    ,sa,  .,  .,master,BRKR TASK       ,0,36,11/28 16:13:40,                                              ,18   ,0    
19   ,sleeping                      ,sa,  .,  .,master,TASK MANAGER    ,0,0,11/28 16:13:40,                                              ,19   ,0    
20   ,BACKGROUND                    ,sa,  .,23   ,test-db,TASK MANAGER    ,0,1,11/28 16:13:40,                                              ,20   ,0    
21   ,BACKGROUND                    ,sa,  .,23   ,test-db,TASK MANAGER    ,0,1,11/28 16:13:40,                                              ,21   ,0    
22   ,BACKGROUND                    ,sa,  .,  .,msdb,DELETE          ,6094,835,11/28 16:13:40,                                              ,22   ,0    
23   ,BACKGROUND                    ,sa,  .,21   ,test-db,TASK MANAGER    ,0,0,11/28 16:13:40,                                              ,23   ,0    
24   ,sleeping                      ,sa,  .,  .,master,TASK MANAGER    ,0,0,11/28 16:13:40,                                              ,24   ,0    
25   ,sleeping                      ,sa,  .,  .,master,TASK MANAGER    ,0,0,11/28 16:13:40,                                              ,25   ,0    
26   ,sleeping                      ,sa,  .,  .,master,TASK MANAGER    ,0,41,11/28 16:13:40,                                              ,26   ,0    
27   ,BACKGROUND                    ,sa,  .,  .,master,TRACE QUEUE TASK,3047,1680,11/28 16:13:40,                                              ,27   ,0    
28   ,sleeping                      ,sa,  .,  .,master,TASK MANAGER    ,0,5,11/28 16:13:40,                                              ,28   ,0    
29   ,sleeping                      ,sa,  .,  .,master,TASK MANAGER    ,0,0,11/28 16:13:40,                                              ,29   ,0    
30   ,sleeping                      ,sa,  .,  .,master,TASK MANAGER    ,0,0,11/28 16:13:40,                                              ,30   ,0    
31   ,sleeping                      ,sa,  .,  .,master,TASK MANAGER    ,0,0,11/28 16:13:40,                                              ,31   ,0    
51   ,RUNNABLE                      ,DY-EPO46\Administrator,DY-EPO46,  .,master,SELECT INTO     ,110,64,11/28 16:30:44,Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query,51   ,0    
52   ,sleeping                      ,DY-EPO46\Administrator,DY-EPO46,  .,master,AWAITING COMMAND,156,14,11/28 16:16:39,Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio        ,52   ,0    
53   ,sleeping                      ,DY-EPO46\Administrator,DY-EPO46,  .,test-db,AWAITING COMMAND,16,16,11/28 16:30:40,Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Query,53   ,0
```

On searching for this problem I found out that people have faced similar problem but I was unable to find out the root cause and debug steps for this problem. Stopping the SQL server is provided as a solution to kick out these background processes but this is not a feasible in our case as code to restore DB runs very frequently resulting in this problem at a good frequency.

I also made sure that SQL Server Agent is not running. The SQL services running on server are SQL server, SQL Server Browser and SQL Server VSS Writer.